# Different keys and IV when using OpenSSL on command line and with a C++ program

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I have an encrypted file where I know the used password and the salt. The file was encrypted with the following credentials:

- Cipher: `aes-128-cbc`
- Hash: `sha1`
- Iter: `5`
- Password: `8P0puxB5OVUFI6uX`
- Salt: `MarkRobs` --> hex: `4d61726b526f6273`

All the following commands and code was tested on Linux with *openssl 3.1*.

When I use the command line with:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k "8P0puxB5OVUFI6uX" -S 4d61726b526f6273 -d -p -iter 5 -md sha1 -bufsize 1024 -in file.enc -out prj.xma -nosalt
```

I get the following key and iv:

```
key=5864BC3B9AAD200975546C1B0FF6F4CF
iv =FB14855AC59E4C541C48D78891B14495
```

With my small program I get the following key and IV:

```
Using passw.: 8P0puxB5OVUFI6uX (38 50 30 70 75 78 42 35 4f 56 55 46 49 36 75 58)
Using salt:   MarkRobs (4d 61 72 6b 52 6f 62 73)
Using key:    14 14 1d 8a 68 ba c6 2b 76 5e ff 05 86 b8 e8 55
Using IV:     c0 be c4 96 c9 1b 77 ed 3a 1c 53 f7 18 8f d5 98
```

Here is the code I implemented:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

#include "scramble.h"
#include "utils.h"

using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ios_base;
using std::ios;
using std::exception;
using std::min;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

#define CHUNK_SIZE          1024
#define OSSL_SUCCESS        1
#define OSSL_ERROR          0
#define AES128_KEY_SIZE     16
#define AES128_SALT_SIZE    8

Scramble::Scramble()
{
    mCtx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

    if (!mCtx)
        cerr << "Error getting new context!" << endl;
}

bool Scramble::aesInit(const string& key, const string& salt, bool encrypt)
{
    if (mAesInitialized)
        return true;

    if (!mCtx)
    {
        cerr << "No context available! Initialisation failed!" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    int keySize;
    int count = 5;      // Number iterations

    const EVP_MD *md = EVP_sha1();
    const EVP_CIPHER *pCipher = EVP_aes_128_cbc();

    if (!md)
    {
        cerr << "Error getting SHA1 hash function!" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (!pCipher)
    {
        cerr << "Error getting the AES128-CBC cipher algorithm!" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    memset(mAesSalt, 0, AES128_SALT_SIZE);
    memcpy(mAesSalt, salt.c_str(), min((size_t)AES128_SALT_SIZE, salt.length()));
    // Initialize the key and IV with 0
    memset(mAesKey, 0, AES128_KEY_SIZE);
    memset(mAesIV, 0, AES128_KEY_SIZE);

    keySize = EVP_BytesToKey(pCipher, md, (unsigned char *)salt.c_str(), (unsigned char *)key.c_str(), key.length(), count, mAesKey, mAesIV);

    if (keySize == AES128_KEY_SIZE)
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(mCtx);

        if (encrypt)
        {
            if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(mCtx, pCipher, nullptr, mAesKey, mAesIV) != OSSL_SUCCESS)
            {
                cerr << "Error initializing decrypting!" << endl;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(mCtx, pCipher, nullptr, mAesKey, mAesIV) != OSSL_SUCCESS)
            {
                cerr << "Error initializing decrypting!" << endl;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Key size is " << (keySize * 8) << " bits - should be 128 bits" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    mAesInitialized = true;
    return mAesInitialized;
}
```

Why is this difference and what must I change to get identical key and IV?

BTW: The original file was encrypted on a Windows by using the library `LIBEAY32.DLL` and the key and IV is different then on Linux although the same C++ code as shown above was used. This I don't understand. What I'm missing?

Comment: The `-iter` option also *implicitly* enables PBKDF2 (as if the `-pbkdf2` option had been explicitly set), see [*openssl-enc*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html), i.e. the key derivation function used in the OpenSSL statement is not `EVP_BytesToKey()` but PBKDF2. The key derivation performed by OpenSSL with `EVP_BytesToKey()` applies an iteration count of 1, which cannot be changed (this low value is one of the reasons why this key derivation is considered insecure).

Comment: If I understand you correct it means, that I can't reproduce the key and IV on command line.

Comment: If you mean a key and IV derived with `EVP_BytesToKey()` and an iteration count of 5, then no. The CLI only allows PBKDF2 to be used with an arbitrary iteration count (e.g. 5) or the deprecated `EVP_BytesToKey()` with a fixed iteration count of 1.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It clears things a little for me. The second problem remains. I've based my source above from a Windows C++ program and compiled it on Linux. Because on both OS the same functions with the same credentials are used I expected the encrypted files to be decrypted successfully. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I have no Windows to compile the code there nor do I have experience with this gaming console, but the library `LIBEAY32.DLL` seems to be an older implementation of Openssl. Why is the result different on the OSs?

Comment: The key and IV generated by your C code on Linux and OpenSSL v3.1 match those generated in my environment, namely Windows 10 and OpenSSL v3.0, and also match the expected values for `EVP_BytesToKey()`, see e.g. here on [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Derive_EVP_key(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'8P0puxB5OVUFI6uX'%7D,256,5,'SHA1',%7B'option':'Hex','string':'4d61726b526f6273%20'%7D)).

Comment: The name of the library reveals that the original file was created with a relatively old version, because *libeay32.dll* was renamed to *libcrypto.dll* as of v1.1.0, see [here](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/1931). But although a bug or breaking change cannot be ruled out, it seems more likely to me that a difference in the parameters (different password, different digest, etc.) is the cause of the decryption failure. Note that as of v1.1.0, also the default digest has been changed from MD5 to SHA-256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve my problem. It turned out that it was my fault because I had a typo in the password. But I want to clarify a few things.

The function `EVP_BytesToKey()` hasn't changed in openssl. It doesn't matter which version of openssl is used. If you call this function with the parameters as in my code example, the result is always the same.

In my example you see that the digest is fixed to `sha1` and that there is a salt given. This means that the default options, who may have changed over the versions, are overwritten. The way the function is called in the example guaranties that the result remains the same.

If the digest, the password and the salt is correct, then the file, provided the file was encrypted with the same credentials, can be decrypted successfully. And so it was for my problem. Once the password was correct, it worked.